# Is there a way to make multiple columns be governed by a single one in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

basically i want to know if it is possible to have multiple columns governed by a single one in Mysql, just like in excel, so when i call the "dad" column i get the "sons" columns. Thanks in advance!

So using [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOPoP.png) as example, i want to select column1 and be returned column2 and column3, and the columns can't be joined, i need to call column1 and be returned 2 and 3 as separated columns.

Answer (score 2):

The most important things to understand about a relational database system are rows and columns, so each row represents an object. So you can read data horizontally rather than vertically, because two or more rows indicate the presence of two or more objects.